# casting derived classes into each other

Tags: c#, inheritance

As I understand, casting one derived class to another is not allowed, so assuming `ClassB` and `ClassC` derive from the same `ClassA`, this will NOT work:

```
ClassB b = new ClassB();

ClassC c = new ClassC();

c = b;
```

But the following code WORKS and I can't quite understand why:

```
ClassA b = new ClassB();

ClassA c = new ClassC();

c = b;
```

Can anyone give me a detailed explanation of what is going on here?

Comment: the 2nd example looks like something that compiles, but will crash at run time.

Comment: The second example looks like normal polymorphism - `b` and `c` are both references to the base class, there is no "sidecasting" happening here

Comment: @wotanii Why would it crash?  `ClassC` and `ClassB` are both derived from `ClassA` so it's a perfectly valid assignment at compile-time and run-time.

Comment: @Vikhram What issue is there to flag?  It's a perfectly valid reference assignment.

Comment: @Vikhram It's not destined to fail. It works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to change your types in the following way to see if it makes the situation clearer:

```
ClassA --> Animal
ClassB --> Tiger
ClassC --> Giraffe
```

In this example:

```
Tiger b = new Tiger();

Giraffe c = new Giraffe();

c = b;
```

The `c` variable must reference an instance of type `Giraffe`.  Trying to assign it a reference to a `Tiger` is not valid because a `Tiger` is not a `Giraffe`.

Your next example:

```
Animal b = new Tiger();

Animal c = new Giraffe();

c = b;
```

Is valid because both `Giraffe` and `Tiger` are `Animal`s, so it's perfectly fine to reference either a `Tiger` or a `Giraffe` from a variable that must reference an `Animal`

Note that NONE of this code changes the actual types of the objects created.  `c` and `b` are just *references* to objects.  When you say

```
c = b;
```

All you are doing is changing the object that `c` *references* - it now references the same object that `b` does.  The object that `c` *used* to point to is now orphaned (there is no reference to it anywhere).

If you then did

```
b.Name = "Sam";
```

You'd see that change reflected both through the `b` reference and the `c` reference.

Comment: The object that c used to point to is not orphaned. did you meant to say "now" instead of not? Otherwise im not sure i understand

Comment: @Ecnerwal Yes I did.  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you set up the classes like this:

```
class ClassA
{
    public int a;
}

class ClassB : ClassA
{
    public string b;
}
```

then you can do this:

```
ClassA B = new ClassB();
B.a = 1;
```

but not this:

```
B.b = "b";
```

The compiler complains that ClassA does not contain a definition for 'b'. In other words, it only treats B as if it were a ClassA. That is why you can cast from C to B.

Comment: It's not casting. It's just reassigning a variable (of reference type `ClassA`)